# Is there a way to create datasource through excel file in SpagoBI

Tags: excel, datasource, spagobi

Is there a way to create datasource through excel file in SpagoBI os that we can do the CRUD operations in the data source..

Answer (score 0):

No, you can upload an excel file as a SpagoBI data set, but it is exposed as a read only source of data for reports .  C(R)UD ops on that file would need to be supported through other means .